# JXLS2, XLSCommentBuilder and row overwrite white iterating over the passed collection

Tags: jxls

I have rather simple XLS template, and one of the rows is annotated with the comment on the cell **A10**:

```
jx:each(items="obj.reportRows" var="reportRow" lastCell="H10")
```

it works well - takes the collection and adds all the data from it, however it does **overwrite** some static cell data that is **below** the row **A**, instead of inserting the generated rows.

Looks like there's no attribute for the **each** command that controls whether the rows should be inserted or overwritten.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include those static cells into **jx:area** tag.

In this case they should be shifted down as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
shiftMode="adjacent"
```

is what i add to my "each" command. I'll explain more...

For simple cases like this you can add a comment in your excel template at cell "A1" that represents the last row and column in your sheet. Lets say your last static cell is at M1 then you would add the following comment to cell "A1"

```
jx:area(lastCell="M10")
```

then you would change your "each" command to

```
jx:each(items="obj.reportRows" var="reportRow" lastCell="H10" shiftMode="adjacent")
```

This will insert the row as you would like without having to add "area" tags to static cells.

Answer (score 0):

Include all rows (table + static cells below table) into one big
**jx:area**.

This will save static cells from disappearing.